# Regex - to accept latin/ucs2 characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex to accept latin/UCS2 characters. But I am getting error while doing that. In the following code, the 'text1' should pass for the pattern. I am still working on this. can anyone please help me in fxing this?

```
    String text1 = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@"
                    + "{|}~¡ ";
            String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\*\\?\\$\\[\\]\\(\\)\\|\\{\\}\\/\\'\\#\\~\\.,;\"\\<=\\>-@%&!+:~¡   ]+$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text1);
    if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("true");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is not working? Is the pattern not matching or is there an error message?

What I see first you have escaped so many characters, that doesn't need to be escaped and an important one is not escaped.

In a character class there are only a few characters that have a special meaning `[]-` and `^` when it is at the first position. You haven't escaped the `-`, this can cause an error, so try:

```
String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9*?$\\[\\]()|{}/'#~.,;\"<=>\\-@%&!+:~¡ £¤¥ §¿ ÄÅÆÇÉÑÖØÜßàäåæ èéìñòöøùü  ]+$";
```

The next thing is: Have a look at [Unicode Properties/Scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop). You can e.g. use `\\p{L}` to match a letter in any language.

```
String pattern = "^[\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9*?$\\[\\]()|{}/'#~.,;\"<=>\\-@%&!+:~¡ £¤¥ §¿]+$";
```

Would match all letters you had in your class **and more**!